# What is the better way to work with view controllers?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

Take into account a simple app with four screens (A, B, C and D) into a navigation stack. The navigation is ordered alphabetically A -> B -> C -> D.

In that situation I'm used to create a member variable in the view controller that shows another one. In my example, A keeps a reference to B, B to C and C to D.

Those references are retained in memory until owner controller is released. I use this approach to minimize creations of controllers and to gain some optimization when showing a screen previously shown.

But I don't know if it's better to create and autorelease each controller every time is needed, without retaining it. There will be more creations but the memory used in a portion of time will be less.

What is the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is use `UINavigationController`.
This class provides set of methods to work with view controllers. There are several easiest methods to work with stack, like push and pop and several more complicated. For example, you may retrieve array of all controllers in the stack, then reorder/delete controller/add controller/... them as you want, and push this array.
This mechanism should allow do to every things you want.

In my opinion save reference to the other controller is not correct. Create new controller it is cheap operation and should not take much time. If you are creating/retrieving data data during controller initialization, just redesign your model level (you can simply do not release it if want save data).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is not to let view controllers retain the next one. `UINavigationController` automatically retains every view controller added to the stack so you don't have to. But if you try to push to the stack an initialized view controller that is already in the same stack, you're in for some surprising crashes/exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Kyr, I already knew that. What I'm doing is to keep the reference to push the same instance if needed again. For example, this navigation A->B->C<-B. I pushed C controller so my B controller has a reference to C but now C is not in the stack, so, if I don't retain the reference, the navigation controller released it. Keeping that reference I'm avoiding the creation of C again when needed. My question: is that correct?

Comment: Not entirely. If you retain the reference to C, you should push that exact referenced object into stack to avoid recreation. 
If initialization process for your view controllers is time/resource expensive, better create some middle singleton controller to store references to your VCs. Just don't make them dependent on one another.

Comment: The singleton mediator is an option that I'm beginning to use in new projects. I likes it but maybe is not the better solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` keeps the information of the view `C` when you pop back to `B`. Just when you'll push to `C` again, check if it's `nil`. If it's not nil, push the older one. It's a good approach and will not affect any aspect of your app. It will just be a pain, if you need to change values on `C`, because of the changes of `B`.